# Two-Factor Authentication for a tomcat java web application

Tags: java, authentication, tomcat, web-applications, two-factor-authentication

I have implemented a simple java web application with tomcat realm authentication(Custom FORM authentication). Now, I'm trying to add a second authentication page for the user(two-factor authentication, I'm using Google authenticator). As far as I have referred the Tomcat documentation, we can specify only one login-config.

I tried adding a filter and also tried managing whether the user has finished the Two-Factor authentication manually with session and tokens.

Is there a way to add the second authentication in the web.xml or the server.xml. So, tomcat should handle whether the user has finished both the authentication.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello! Welcome to SO. In order to get answers, you should probably include in your question some code illustrating what you tried, and output showing what went wrong and at which point.

Comment: I would have included it, but there is no error in the implementation. I was asking for a suggestion for implementing the 2FA. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomcat only starts one login process. That process may decide to ask the user for more than one credential but tomcat is not aware of it.

So, you should create a filter and/or login servlet that handles authentication for the tomcat container. That filter/servlet (combination) must prompt for all desired credentials.

If you do not use a framework for your application that already has an authentication layer, you are essentially writing your own 2FA implementation.

Comment: I have already implemented the 2FA with filters. What I'm trying to ask is that, is there a way to automatically to redirect to the second login page(2FA) once the user finishes the first authentication, by changing the <security-constraints> and <login-config>. We should not specify/ manually redirect to the 2FA page to complete the authentication. Tomcat should detect that there are two authentications should be done, so the user should not be able to access the application resources without completing the authentication process(s).

Comment: OK, what I am trying to say is that tomcat is not a 2FA authentication framework. It only knows that authentication is needed, not which kind. So, your first factor should redirect to the second factor if necessary.

Comment: Oh, Okay. Is it possible to configure two login pages in the web.xml? The required flow is login_1 -> login_2->Home page. Thanks.

Comment: You can configure more than one `filter-mapping` for the same `url-pattern` of course. Order in web.xml is the order of execution.